# Visual Studio - Rebuild fails (link), Clean and Build works

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I have a Visual Studio solution. It has 10 projects. When I do a "Clean", then "Build", the solution builds properly and everything works fine. However, when I do a "Rebuild", I get a linkage error:
error LNK1104: cannot open file '{path} \ {name of project 6}.lib'

This error is triggered from project 10.

```
Build Order: <br>
project 1 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 2 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 3 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 4 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 5 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 6 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 7 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 8 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 9 (.lib) - Fine <br>
project 10 (.exe) - The project 6 library file created earlier disappears and project 10 cannot build, as it needs the project 6 library file.
```

I'm hoping that someone may be able to point me to some project properties that may be messed up. I'm not sure why it's only complaining about project 6.

Comment: You need to add dependencies so that VS knows to build one project before another. Right click on the project and select "Build Dependencies...".

Comment: I have the same issue and my build order is ok and so are my deps

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue. The build order is fine (which can also be seen in the log output), but the output file of a previous build step is missing somehow or gets deleted by the next build step.

I solved the issue by giving each project an own Intermediate Directory at `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Intermediate Directory`.